# select box how to set set first value when values comes from db

Tags: drop-down-menu

Im making a selectbox with the values from my DB, and I want the first value to be "make a choice".

How can it be done?
I have this code..

```
                <tr>
                <td width="180" height="30"><label for="valgtkon" class="labelLeft">Vælg konkurrencetype</label></td> 
                <td><select id="valgtTitel" name="valgtTitel" onchange="run()">                  
                <?php
                $virksomhedsID = $_SESSION['virkID'];
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM konkurrenceType ORDER BY konkurrenceType.kontypeID";
                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());                  

                while($rowSelect = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                { 
                    $kontypeTitel = $rowSelect['kontypeTitel'];
                    $kontypeID = $rowSelect['kontypeID'];

                    echo '<option value="' . $kontypeID . '">' . $kontypeTitel . '</option>';
                }?>                    
                </select></td>
                <script>
                function run() {
                    document.getElementById("valgtID").value = document.getElementById("valgtTitel").value;
                }
                </script>


                <td><input type="text" name="valgtID" id="valgtID"/></td>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the while loop, add another echo statement creating the option for the first "make a choice" option, then add some validation on submission to make sure they selected a different choice from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Set  **option** first **option** Before the database result, so place it outside the php after the **select** tag, that should do the trick!

**bold** text must represent the tags.
(Im on my iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Jep I've got it. Thank you.

```
            <tr>
                <td width="180" height="30"><label for="valgtkon" class="labelLeft">Vælg konkurrencetype</label></td> 
                <td><select id="valgtTitel" name="valgtTitel" onchange="run()">                  
                <?php
                $virksomhedsID = $_SESSION['virkID'];
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM konkurrenceType ORDER BY konkurrenceType.kontypeID";
                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());                  

                echo '<option value="Vælg type">Vælg type</option>';

                while($rowSelect = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                { 
                    $kontypeTitel = $rowSelect['kontypeTitel'];
                    $kontypeID = $rowSelect['kontypeID'];

                    echo '<option value="' . $kontypeID . '">' . $kontypeTitel . '</option>';
                }?>                    
                </select></td>
                <script>
                function run() {
                    document.getElementById("valgtID").value = document.getElementById("valgtTitel").value;
                }
                </script>


                <td><input type="text" name="valgtID" id="valgtID"/></td>
                </tr>
```